# Hibernate ClassCastException when retrieving a class from query.getResultList

Tags: oracle, hibernate, classcastexception

I created a small SpringBoot App which is used together with Hibernate to work with our Oracle Databse.

But I ran into the following Problem:

Whenever I load an Object from the database with SessionFactory.createQuery() and then query.getResultList(). I do get a List of Results with the correct Class annotations (when looking at the code in debug mode). But I cannot do MyClass x = list.get(0), even though the list is a List of MyClass. I can only get an Object but cannot "cast" to the correct class.

Uidnr is a simple Class with no join tables or any other dependencies on other tables form the database. Its only BigDecimal's, String's and Timestamp's.

Here is the code and configs of everything:

POST Endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/e10", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String e10() {

  Database db = new Database();
  List<Uidnr> bel = db.getUidnrList(new BigDecimal("1009316"));
  Uidnr element = bel.get(0); //CLASSCASTEXCEPTION HERE!!!

  return element.getNr();
}
```

Method to get the Class from Database:

```
public List<Uidnr> getUidnrList(BigDecimal id) {

   SessionFactory factory = null;
   List<Uidnr> uidnr = new ArrayList<Uidnr>();
   Session session = null;

   try {

      factory = getSessionFactory();
      session = factory.openSession();

      Query<Uidnr> query = session.createQuery("from Uidnr where adrid=:sblid", Uidnr.class);
      query.setParameter("sblid", id);
      uidnr = query.getResultList(); //This is a List<Uidnr

   } catch (HibernateException ex) {
      logger.error("Error loading Sendungen.", ex);
   } finally {
      close(factory, session);
   }

   return uidnr;
}
```

SessionFactory:

```
private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

  SessionFactory sf = null;
  File optextconf = new File("conf/hibernate.cfg.xml");
  Configuration c = new Configuration();

  if (optextconf.exists()) {
     c.configure(optextconf);
     c.addResource("eu/lbase/invsvc/app/model/internal/Uidnr.hbm.xml");
     sf = c.buildSessionFactory();
     logger.info("Session factory loaded from external file {}.", optextconf.getAbsolutePath());
  } else {
     logger.error("Configuration {} not found. Can not connect to database.", optextconf.getAbsolutePath());
  }
  return sf;
}
```

Uidnr.hbm.xml file located under src/main/resources, in a package called eu.lbase.invsvc.app.model.internal:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="eu.lbase.invsvc.app.model.internal.Uidnr" table="SUID_UIDNR">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="adrid" column="UID_ADRID" />
            <key-property name="staid" column="UID_STAID" />
        </composite-id>
        <property name="nr" column="UID_NR"/>
        <property name="stnr" column="UID_STNR"/>
        <property name="deflt" column="UID_DEFLT"/>
        <property name="aend" column="UID_AEND"/>
        <property name="usrid" column="UID_USRID"/>
        <property name="stktonr" column="UID_STKTONR"/>
        <property name="zoktonr" column="UID_ZOKTONR"/>
        <property name="vollmacht" column="UID_VOLLMACHT"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: eu.lbase.invsvc.app.model.internal.Uidnr cannot be cast to eu.lbase.invsvc.app.model.internal.Uidnr
at eu.lbase.invsvc.app.controller.WebController.e10(WebController.java:91) ~[main/:na]
```

Some Tests:

```
System.out.println(bel.getClass()); //class java.util.ArrayList
Object test = bel.get(0);
System.out.println(test.getClass()); //class eu.lbase.invsvc.app.model.internal.Uidnr
System.out.println(bel.get(0) instanceof eu.lbase.invsvc.app.model.internal.Uidnr); //false
```

Comment: Do you have two classes named Uidnr in your project?
Also, please post your hibernate entity Uidnr which you are trying to fetch from database

Comment: I added the Uidnr.hbm.xml configuration.
Could the problem be, that both (the Uidnr.java and uidnr.hbm.xml) have the same package names? Uidnr.java is in src/main/java/eu.lbase.invsvc.app.model.internal and Uidnr.hbm.xml is in src/main/resources/eu.lbase.invsvc.app.model.internal.

Also, there is only 1 class called Uidnr with 1 hibernate mapping file Uidnr.hbm.xml

Comment: Yes that could be an issue...canyou try changing the name of your configuration file?